# How to access the same bookmarks folder from separate bookmarks paths in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there a way (or extension) to share the same bookmarks folder between other bookmarks folders? I don't want to share them with other people; I just want to be able to get to the same folder of links from more than a single bookmarks folder path.